# Como integrar uma aplicação Android com um servidor em Python + DB?

Tags: android, python, cliente-servidor

Boa tarde a todos! Sou estudante de Ciência da Computação, porém ainda não tive a oportunidade de ter uma experiência mais profunda com programação, envolvendo as integrações necessárias em aplicativos e sistemas, e gostaria muito de ter uma noção por cima do que vou precisar.

De maneira resumida, tenho um projeto no qual pretendo desenvolver um aplicativo Android, o qual atuará quase que somente como front, enviando os dados ao meu servidor em Python, o qual armazenará os mesmos no banco respectivo, realizará algoritmos de Machine Learning sobre esses dados, e retornará isso ao meu aplicativo, trazendo para o front (exibindo na tela). Basicamente será um aplicativo de questões e respostas, como quizzes.

A minha dúvida é: como farei para, através do meu aplicativo, acessar minha aplicação em Python (ou fazer as chamadas), retorná-las e afins? Pois para a integração Python<->DB já analisei algumas possibilidades e provavelmente irei utilizar a lib pymysql, porém não consegui encontrar algo assim para o lado de Android<->Python (por exemplo, o usuário acertou 3 questões, eu envio esse inteiro para a minha aplicação Python e nela são chamadas as funções respectivas para os cálculos).

Li um pouco sobre "web services", é necessário algo assim para o que eu desejo? Qualquer recomendação de materiais ou sites onde eu possa estudar isso mais a fundo é muito bem vinda!

Agradeço desde já.

Edit 1: Inicialmente, gostaria apenas de criar uma conexão básica, com a boa e velha tela de login, isto é, desejo criar uma autenticação realizada pelo meu server-side (Python + DB). A partir disto, desejo explorar as partes conjuntamente e individualmente.

Solicito, se possível, algum exemplo específico desse procedimento, algo como "Android - ferramenta X - servidor - ferramenta Y - banco de dados", ou seja, a maneira como isso tudo se conecta, citando ferramentas, para que a partir desse exemplo eu possa procurar ferramentas similares e encontrar a que melhor me atender. Creio que um exemplo gráfico elucidaria muito minhas dúvidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim - 
como você já deve ter entendido, sua aplicação Python vai ficar num servidor na nuvem. Vários frameworks para android permitem que você faça uma aplicaão que vai buscar resultados na nuvem por meio de web-services. Frameworks para criação de aplicativos "html5" como o Ionic e o Electron, permitem o uso direto de web-services, assim como a combinação de tecnologias como Angular ou React que permitem outras formas de escrever a aplicação.

Do lado do Python, o que você vai ter é um servidor (pode ser um Virtual Private Server, ou um serviço de hospedagem como o Heroku ou o redhatOpenShift) - nele é configurada uma rota para sua aplicação Python, que via de regra deve responder usando o padrão "WSGI". Por outro lado, você escreve sua aplicação Python respondendo WSGI, e não tem que se preocupar com as configurações de produção durante o desenvolvimento.

Talvez uma das formas mais simples de se criar um conjunto de webservices em Python seja usando o framework Flask - embora qualquer dos framworks web mais populares vá servir (Django, Bottle, Web2py, Pyramid):  esses frameworks vão conter uma série de utilidades e serviços de forma que você não tenha que re-inventar a roda para zilhões de coisas - como manter a independência entre requests, manter um pool de conexões com o banco de dados,obter e validar dados de formulários ou requisições HTTP, evitam ataques de cross-site-scripting, (XSS), e essa lista poderia crescer bastante.

Aqui tem um blog post que dá o caminho das pedras para fazer com Flask:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

(como você pode ver, escrever um exemplo funcionando aqui, incluindo as instruções de configuração para desenvolvimento seria o equivalente a um capítulo de livro).

A última recomendação que deixo é *não* tentar usar o SQL diretamente - você vai ter muito mais flexibilidade e facilidade para criar novos modelos na sua aplicação se usar um ORM -"Object Relational Mapper". O mais usado para Python é o [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) - e é fácil achar instruções de integração do mesmo com todos os frameworks python. A não ser que você opte por usar [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) como framework, nesse caso ele usa um ORM próprio que é bem prático também.

Comment: Na verdade não havia entendido não hahahaha

A maneira como eu via era usar um computador em minha casa como servidor, e não em nuvem. Na realidade não tenho noção nenhuma de ambos, e não sei qual é a alternativa mais simples.

Dito isto, qual a melhor alternativa (no quesito facilidade) de servidor? Hospedar o meu server-side em um serviço de nuvem ou usar o meu próprio computador?

Comment: usar o seu comutador para desenvolver, e colocar na nuvem para quando for pra seus amigos/usuarios finais usarem. Há algumas opções gratuitas para baixo uso - procure por "pythonanywhere" e "heroku", por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi! No meu caso, é um projeto de faculdade, portanto ainda não tenho planos para disponibiliza-lo a outrem, sendo assim, poderia usar apenas o computador por enquanto, correto? Creio que já tive contato com o "heroku", darei uma estudada, muito obrigado!

Comment: Uma coisa legal, e se você conseguir é um "case" pra por online é criar uma aplicação html5 do Android com electron ou outro, usando o "Brython"; Brython é uma implementação de Python feita inteira em Javascript, para rodar direto no Browser. Tecnicamente é um projeto javascript que deixa você programar front-end direto em Python. Mas ninguem documentou ainda os passos para criar um app Python usando ele direto. (dai no caso, tem o "internal storage' - api de html5 que dá pra usar em vez de um db)