# É uma boa ideia usar JSON como database?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, json, mobile, python-kivy

Estou fazendo um projeto de aplicativo para celular. Usando Python e Kivy. Meu projeto tem três classes principais a serem salvas em um banco de dados (é uma aplicação de venda de ingressos): Ingressos, Eventos e Usuários.

Pesquisando, vi que o JSON a principio é bem fácil de trabalhar, e ele é recomendado na documentação do Kivy como um dos métodos usuais de permanência de dados.

Porém me surgiram algumas dúvidas (que eu, infelizmente, não consegui sanar em pesquisas simples ou na documentação). A principal: é viável manter JSON como meu banco de dados? Considerando que o app possa crescer em números.

Devo fazer um arquivo JSON para cada classe ? (um para usuários, um para ingressos e um para eventos)

É isso. Se tiverem alguma recomendação de leitura que possa me sanar essas dúvidas, eu agradeço muito. Estou começando com as 3 tecnologias, isso deve justificar as dúvidas simples.

Desde já, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: JSON é uma mera especificação de formato. Database são dados armazenados em algum lugar (independente de formato, tem a questão de armazenamento); Seria legal você [edit] e explicar melhor a relação que pretende entre as duas coisas pra ficar mais fácil de entender o problema de fato. Um JSON por si só não tem como ser um Database.

Comment: Não sei como editar isso para melhorar o entendimento. Mas acho que você já me ajudou. JSON então é só um formato? Que tecnologia eu poderia usar junto a ele então para ter um banco de dados funcional ?

Comment: Precisa gravar os dados em algum lugar. Se é Python e vai armazenar localmente (no próprio dispositivo que roda a aplicação), tem o SQLite, que é poderoso e super leve.

Comment: Pretendo gravar os dados não-localmente, afinal serão os mesmos para diversos usuários. Ainda não estou conseguindo entender na verdade. A relação entre o JSON e os bancos de dados, eu achava que ele era uma forma de armazenar os dados suficientemente boa para o que eu quero.

Comment: Nesse caso o JSON pode ser um formato para "conversar" com o servidor remoto, onde rodará o DB. http://json.org - lá a aplicação decodificará o JSON e fará as operações num DB.

Comment: Acho que estou entendo. Você pode me recomendar alguma ferramenta então para usar como o servidor remoto onde rodará o meu DB? Ou qual seria o passo seguinte para o meu estudo

Comment: Seria legal uma busca aqui no site mesmo, e uma espiada nos itens relacionados aí ao lado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272434/70

Comment: Vim trabalhando em um projeto que se assemelha ao que você procurava, uma database baseada em JSON. JSON é um formato de arquivo que remete a um objeto em javascript (JavaScript Object Notation). No python temos o "dict" que se assemelha a um objeto em JS, mas com diferenças. Ao invés de criar um DB baseado no JSON, fiz algo mais semelhante à sintaxe da dict. Criei uma sintaxe própria para diferenciar os dados na hora de editar manualmente, mas é bastante funcional e prática.
Se quiser acompanhar o projeto ou dar alguma sugestão, segue o [link](https://github.com/HidekiHrk/JLDB)

Answer (score 2):

Complementando o `Alex Ayub`:

Se seu banco de dados é relacional (isto é, cada dataset é uma tabela com colunas fixas) então você pode usar o SQLite (`import sqlite3 as lite`). Porém, se você pretende manter esse aplicativo (e a base) num seridor tipo da AWS (e está preocupado em escalabilidade, conformidade e adm em geral) você deverá usar o AWS RDS (nesse caso terá que usar o MySQL ou outra solução de servidor como SQL Server ou o Maria DB, etc; mas não o SQLite).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica !

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` é um formato , por exemplo :

```
Cliente = {
  Nome: 'Fulano',
  Sobrenome: 'teste',
  Idade: 36
}
```

Este é um exemplo de `json`, ele é um formato, aliás hoje padrão para se trabalhar com a comunicação entre `FrontEnd` e `BackEnd(Apis)`, o padrão de envio e recebimento dos dados entre as partes transitam neste formato na maioria das vezes, ainda mais com o padrão `restful das API's`. Como dito acima é um formato, hoje existem bancos de dados `NOSQL` que trabalham quase que instantaneamente com `JSON`, pois funcionam com o mesmo padrão de documentos, por exemplo o `MongoDB`. Mas se você quiser gravar em um banco de dados, basta colocar o `JSON` no padrão que você quer e que o banco de dados que você escolheu entenda, então salve os dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!